# How would I go about making my own Application protocol similar to http/https?

Tags: http, https, protocols

I don't know where to start especially with what programming language and in what kind of environment. I know I would need 2 different types, a server which receives requests and sends the requested material back and a client which sends requests and views requested material but not sure where and how to start.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What is the motivation for this? HTTP/HTTPS are very tried, true and secure protocols that every (almost every) web application communicates via.

I cannot fathom a possible reason to create your own, especially if it seems like you are not quite experienced enough to do so given the very generic question.

My answer would be, don't do this, use HTTP/HTTPs or WebSockets, whatever suits your applications requirements.